# Foreach array_combine with two arrays with different number of elements?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Right now i am combining two arrays, but they are with different number of elements.

Here is the code:

```
preg_match_all('/\"SizeName\":\"([0-9.]+)\"/',$str,$matches);
preg_match_all('/\"SellPrice\":\"([0-9.]+)\"/',$str,$matches1);
echo '<pre>';
    foreach (array_combine($matches[0], $matches1[0]) as $ht => $name) {
echo "$ht - $name<br>";
}
echo '</pre>';
```

I want to ask how i can limit the combine with the lowest number of elements array ?

I saw an advice for resolving this problem with a function like this:

```
function array_combine2($arr1, $arr2) {
    $count = min(count($arr1), count($arr2));
    return array_combine(array_slice($arr1, 0, $count), array_slice($arr2, 0, $count));
}
```

But my question is, does this function will help me and how i can implement it in my code so it will not give me output error:

`Warning:  array_combine() [function.array-combine]: Both parameters should have an equal number of elements`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try array_merge() I think they don't need an equal number of elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"does this function will help me"*? **Yes**

*"how i can implement it in my code so it will not give me output error"*?

1. Paste the function definition for `array_combine2` in your code.
2. Change `array_combine` to `array_combine2` in your `foreach`.

Comment: Thanks your answer works just fine. But now i have another question. How can i get `preg_match_all` after some number of first occurencies ?

Comment: That's a new question for sure.  With a more detailed description.

Comment: Okey then, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25171406/php-preg-match-all-how-to-start-fething-results-after-a-number-of-first-occurenc