# PHP preg_match_all how to start fething results after a number of first occurencies?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Right now i am working on a PHP script which is fetching all occurencies from a text which have `"SizeName":` and here is the code for doing this:

```
preg_match_all('/\"SizeName\":\"([0-9.]+)\"/',$str,$matches);
```

This line of code is fething occurencies from the first time when it finds `"SizeName":`, but how i can make it start printing data after for example the third time when it finds `"SizeName":` ?

Is it possible and how i can achieve it ?

Comment: Your string seems to be json data, use json_decode, follow the tree to find what you need in the array, and select what you want. If you want absolutely use regexes use your pattern and select all results after the third matches, it's probably faster. (but time it if you want).

Comment: @TonnyStruck Could you provide what your data actually looks like?

Comment: As a nudge for the previous comments, out of curiousity, what does this return: `print_r(json_decode($str));`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all('/(?:(?:.*?"SizeName":){2}|\G).*?\K"SizeName":"([0-9.]+)"/s', $str, $matches);
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/eQ0nT2/3)

---

```
(?:             (?# start non-capturing group for alternation)
  (?:           (?# start non-capturing group for repetition)
    .*?         (?# lazily match 0+ characters)
    "SizeName": (?# literally match "SizeName":)
  ){2}          (?# repeat twice)
 |              (?# OR)
  \G            (?# start from last match)
)               (?# end alternation)
.*?             (?# lazily match 0+ characters)
\K              (?# throw away everything to the left)
"SizeName":     (?# literally match "SizeName":)
"([0-9.]+)"     (?# match the number into capture group 1)
```

---

**Notes:**

- You don't need to escape `"`, since it is not a special regex character and you build your PHP String with `'`.
- Change the `{2}` to modify the number of `SizeName` instances to skip (I wasn't sure if you wanted to skip 3 or start from the 3rd).
- The `s` modifier is needed if there are any newline characters between the instances of `SizeName`, since `.*?` will not match newline characters without it.

Comment: This can not work if you put the first entry point at the first position in the alternation. The second entry point (with `\G`) must be at the first position in the alternation. Otherwise `(?:"SizeName":.*?){2}` will be ever matched if there are more than 6 occurences.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, if `\G` is first in the alternation, then it will always match and go straight to capturing the first `SizeName`.  However, I did update this by adding a lazy match before the repeated/neglected `SizeName` in the alternation.  That way it will always match even if there is content before it.

Comment: Absolutly not, since `\G` succeeds only when there is a previous match. And the previous match could be the first two "sizename" or an other previous (`\G`) match.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte According to my answer, am I misunderstanding his concept?

Comment: @hwnd: No I don't think, the only thing is that "no one" (I think to the Ray Charles song when i write that) knows how the data look like. Since it is anchored, I don't see a problem.

Comment: Makes sense @CasimiretHippolyte, thank you much for the demo. I was missing the negative lookahead in `\G(?!\A)`, because I knew that `\G` *also* matched the beginning of the string (which I didn't want).

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of strpos and the preg_match_all's offset. Basically, start your search after the 2nd occurrence of the string.

```
$offset = strpos($str, 'SizeName', strpos($str, 'SizeName', 8) ) + 8;
preg_match_all(
    '/(?:(?:.*?"SizeName":){2}|\G).*?\K"SizeName":"([0-9.]+)"/s', 
    $str, 
    $matches,
    PREG_PATTERN_ORDER,
    $offset
);
```

I'm hard coding the number 8 because that is the string length of 'SizeName'.